# Spring bean session scope for kafka listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-bean

I want a bean that only exists so long as the method annotated with `@KafkaListener` has not returned. And I want there to be a new instance of the bean every time the method is called. Is there a way of doing this that is already baked into Spring Beans?

I want this because with each consumption of a Kafka message I have some global variables that I want all other beans to have access to but not other concurrent calls to the consumer method. I tried making a bean with scope "SimpleThreadScope" but that didn't seem to work consistently.

Comment: What does this bean do that there should be a new copy every time? In general, that sort of thing should be a state object, not a service object.

Comment: No not every time, it should act like the session scope except the initiating function call is not a rest endpoint, rather the consumption of a kafka message. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-